# Ambiguous notation in isomorphic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-isomorphism

Let $U_1=\{z\in\mathbf{C}\mid |z|=1\}\subset \mathbf{C}^*$, where $\mathbf{C}^*$ are the complex numbers exluding $0$ under multiplication.

I am asked to prove that $\boxed{\mathbf{C}^*\cong U_1\times \mathbf{R}^+}$.

Here comes the ambiguity. In some footnote, my lecture notes define $\mathbf{R}^+$ to be the real numbers *under addition*, while I find this definition ambiguous since various texts define $\mathbf{R}^+$ to be the *positive* real numbers *under multiplication*.

Which of the two is $\mathbf{R}^+$ in this particular question? I think it should be the positive real numbers under multiplication, since there is an obvious isomorphism $z\mapsto (z/|z|,|z|)$.

I can also apply some theorem in my lecture notes which states that if $H_1,H_2\subset G$ are subgroups and $H_1 H_2=G$, $H_1$ and $H_2$ commute and $H_1\cap H_2=\{e\}$, then $G\cong H_1\times H_2$. But in the context of $\mathbf{R}^+$ meaning the real numbers under addition, the last condition is not met since the intersection contains both $-1$ and $1$.

Two arguments in favor of $\mathbf{R}^+$ meaning the positive reals under multiplication. Who can give a definite answer to this confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the real numbers greater than $0$ under multiplication. Besides, under addition they don't even form a group. And your obvious isomorphism is a correct answer.

Comment: Under addition they don't form a group? 0 is the identity, -a is the inverse?

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz Does $-a\in\mathbf{R}^+$?

Comment: With all due respect, You are not reading my question properly, my confusion is about R+ meaning ALL reals under addition or POSITIVE reals under multiplication

Comment: @HeinzDoofenschmirtz You are right: I didn't read your question properly. Then my answer is: it doesn't matter, since the group of all real numbers under addition is isomorphic to the group of all real numbers greater than $0$ under multiplication. But I strongly suspec that whover wrote that exercise had the group of all real numbers greater than $0$ under multiplication in his or her mind.

Comment: Thanks! That really helps. So I should first establish $\mathbf{C}^* \cong U_1 \times (\mathbf{R}^+,\cdot)$ using the theorem I described and then use $\mathbf{R}^+,\cdot)\cong (\mathbf{R},+)$? Or is there any shorter way?

Comment: I would forget $(\mathbf{R},+)$. It is quite clear to me that that's not what the author of the exercise had in mind.